case when on many lines resulting out of a group by in teradata
i'm trying to make a concat of a column of a bunch of lines but with some conditions to verify before adding the value of the column, so basically let's say i have a table that contains a userId, a discountCode, and a flag (0,1,2)
userId  discountCode    FLAG 
abo1    remise 1        1
abo1    Remise 2        2
abo1    remise 100%     0
abo1    remise 16%      0
abo2    remise 1        0
abo2    Remise 2        0
abo2    remise 100%     0
abo2    remise 16%      0

what i need is that for each user i have to concatenate the discountCode in one column but on cases :
if all the flags are 0 for that user we take all the discountCodes
if there is a mixt of 0 and other values we do not add the discountCodes that have a flag 0
if all the discount code are <> 0 we add them all.
so the result of the previous data should be :
userId  discountCode
abo1    remise 1 | Remise 2
abo2    remise 1 | Remise 2 |  remise 100% | remise 16%


 TRIM(
    TRAILING ',' FROM (
      XMLAGG(TRIM(COALESCE(discountCode , -1) || '') ) (VARCHAR(1000)) 
    )

i used this function to group the discountCode in one column but i dont know how to check for the conditions of the flags

We can use the SUM() window function to calculate the total for each user. then, we exclude rows where the flag is 0 and the total is greater than 0 by applying the condition WHERE FLAG <> 0 OR SM = 0 :
SELECT userId, TRIM(
                 TRAILING ',' FROM (
                   XMLAGG(TRIM(COALESCE(discountCode , -1) || '') ) (VARCHAR(1000)) 
               ) AS discounts
FROM (
  SELECT userId, 
         discountCode, 
         FLAG, 
         SUM(FLAG) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ) AS SM
  FROM mytable
) as s
WHERE FLAG <> 0 OR SM = 0
GROUP BY userId;

Demo on sql server

Yes, it is the idea i ended up with i did something similar, u subquery to filter the records and then i used the XMLAGG to concat :
select
*
from test
inner join (
select abo,sum(flag) as sflag
from test
group by 1) b
on test.abo=b.abo
and (( b.sflag =0 ) or (  b.sflag <> 0 and test.flag<>0))
